# Skype4COM edited sent messages

Tags: chat, message, edit, skype4com

I would like to use the API 'Skype4COM' to edit already sent messages, I have approached this before but seem to not have any luck in finding a solution that will let me access/edit my last message sent.
I'm sure it has to do with the MessageStatus event but I cannot work out how to edit them/remove them after they have sent.

```
    public void MessageStatus(SKYPE4COMLib.ChatMessage pMessage, SKYPE4COMLib.TChatMessageStatus Status)
    {
        if (Status.Equals(TChatMessageStatus.cmsSent))
        {
            if (pMessage.IsEditable)
            {
                //Remove message/edit message?
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Skype4Py API you can simply do `pMessage.Body = "your text"` which will call the pMessage objects SetBody() function. You should try that.